# Closed form of $ a_n = 1 - \frac{a_{n-1} a_{n-2}}{4} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

Given the sequence $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 1 $ with: $ a_n =  1 - \frac{a_{n-1} a_{n-2}}{4} $

Does there exist a closed form computing $a_n$ ?
At the moment I have a problem getting a grip on the series: I think it is neither monotone increasing nor monotone decreasing but rather fluctuating around some values (it is bounded and thus must have a least one converging subsequence)

As always: I am happy about any constructive hint, comment or answer to the problem.

Comment: mathematica doesn't find anything

Comment: Are you truly interested in finding a closed form, or merely in studying its convergence?

Comment: Jack's deleted solution seems to show, for $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ and $c_n=|b_n|$, that $c_n<\max\{c_{n-1},c_{n-2}\}/2$, which makes $a_n$ Cauchy.

Comment: That would mean the sequence converges, and he calculated $-2+2\sqrt{2}$.